# Can External Tables in Hive Intelligently Identify Partitions?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I need to run this whenever I need to mount partition. Rather than me doing it manually is there a way to auto detect partition in external hive tables

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION()location 'locationpath';
```

Comment: what partition are you adding there; I mean `PARTITION()` its blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recover Partitions (MSCK REPAIR TABLE)

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```

partitions will be add automatically

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic partition, the directory does not need to be created manually. But dynamic partition mode needs to be set to nonstrict, by default it is strict

```
CREATE External TABLE profile (
userId int
)
PARTITIONED BY (city String)
location '/user/test/profile';

set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

hive> insert into profile partition(city) 
      select * from nonpartition;

hive> select * from profile;
OK
1   Chicago
1   Chicago
2   Orlando
```

and in HDFS

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/test/profile
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2016-08-26
22:40 /user/test/profile/city=Chicago
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2016-08-26 
22:40 /user/test/profile/city=Orlando
```